# error waiting for Storage Gateway SMB File Share

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create storage gateway SMB fileshare for s3 through terraform and i am getting unavailable error.

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_storagegateway_smb_file_share" "sg_fileshare" {
  authentication  = "ActiveDirectory"
  gateway_arn     = "arn:aws:storagegateway:${var.region}:${var.account_number}:gateway/${var.gateway_id}"
  location_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::${module.migration_bucket.name}"
  role_arn        = module.sgw_role.role_arn
  smb_acl_enabled = true
  oplocks_enabled = false
}
```

when i run this i am getting below error.

```
Error: error waiting for Storage Gateway SMB File Share 
(arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:01243564785:share/share-57dHUID) to 
create: unexpected state 'UNAVAILABLE', wanted target 'AVAILABLE'. last error: %!s(<nil>)
```

**sgw_assume_role:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "storagegateway.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i have added these policies as well :

```
["AmazonS3FullAccess",
    "AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess",
  "AWSLambda_FullAccess", "AmazonSNSFullAccess"]
```

Comment: Does the role allow storage gateway to assume the role and does it have the necessary permissions to access the S3 bucket?

Comment: yes it has full permissions

Comment: Can you show those permissions by adding them to the question?

Comment: i have updated the question with role and policies which i used for this resource creation